# simple jquery.ajax / webmethod example not working -- how to fix

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I got this simple webmethod example at

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

The live demo works on the site.  I downloaded the sample code and copied the code into my test webapp as follows -- except my sample app not working.  I have the same jquery-1.3.2.min.js in the Scripts folder of my (VS2013) sample app (I have several jquery scripts in this folder).

here is the client script / markup code from my sample app (WebForm3 is the start page)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm3</title>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm3.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script> 

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Your Name : 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code behind -- no errors when running the page -- just the alert not showing up -- am I referencing the url in the ajax incorrectly?

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    var userName = $('#txtUserName').val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'WebForm3.aspx/GetCurrentTime',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: userName }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

Hi Rich, from what I can see your ajax call is mostly correct but you want to make sure you avoid using string concatenation to pass in parameters, you can do the same thing by either using a data hash (i.e JSON.stringify) or pass in a variable you have created to hold the data for the parameter. If this fix doesnt work I would suggest making a variable and loading in the value from txtUserName.ClientID, I can't say for sure but that could be another underlying issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply -- I tried your modified ShowCurrentTime() function and received this error message:                                                                                    Unhandled exception at line 17, column 13 in http://localhost:62595/WebForm3.aspx

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'val'                                                                                                  Do I need a different jquery...js file?

Comment: Hey no problem, I would switch is back to .value then and just confirm that the value inside of it is a string or what you expect. The only reason I changed it from .value to .val() is because jQuery only supports .val() for retreiving values from elements but if it is giving you an error I would try changing it back and seeing what happens.

Comment: I switched back to .value() -- gives me error message.  Then tried without parens, and I am back a square one, not getting any kind of error message or anything.  have you tried this sample to see if it even works?

Comment: If all you want is the value from the textbox aka the users name then I have updated my answer and it does work, I have tested it on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this.  I tried your updated function, and I added a breakpoint.  I did notice that there was nothing in the example the gets the dateTime, so I guess yes just getting the value from the textbox.  When I click the button it does go to the jquery, and I do see the value from the textbox  -- and it goes into the js library -- but still (for me) it does not go to OnSuccess or bring up an alert for failure.  I have tried using jquery-1.3.2.min.js and also tried using jquery-1.8.3.js.  Any ideas appreciated why my version not working (VS2013)

Comment: If it's being weird and acting like that I would suggest writing your Success function like how you have the failure one if you need this code completed soon. Unfortunately I don't have time to continue looking at this right now, you could also add in an Error: function definition to see if its returning errors.

Comment: I created a whole new project and just copied the files to this project rather than copy the code to an empty project.  Now it is working.  Maybe web.config was different?  I will post back when I figure out what is different with this new sample project from the original one.

Comment: Well, everything working correctly now, including your revised jquery function.  I can only conclude it was the evil jquery/json gnomes hindering my sight -- but I overcame them!  many thanks for your help.

Comment: turns out that my original sample app has this line in the RouteConfig file which when I commented it out the webmethod worked correctly 'settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent